# SQL insert not working in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a SQL Insert in my code behind and when I click the button, it seems to update the Textbox control on my page and not my database. Here's the code behind:

```
protected void UpdatePic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO BlogEntryItems(Picture) VALUES (@UpdatedPic)";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    TextBox uPic = (TextBox)DataList1.Items[1].FindControl("BEIPictureField");

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedPic", uPic.Text);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The ASP code is for a button where the OnClick event calls this method:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
<ItemStyle />
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="placePicCenter" runat="server" 
                BorderWidth="1px"
                BorderColor="#EEEEEE"
                ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Picture") %>' /><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="BEIPictureField" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Picture") %>' /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="UpdatePicButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdatePic" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="placeBodyStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PicText1") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What value is returned from `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: If you debug this in visual studio, does the ExecuteNonQuery() run?  Also, how are you checking your database?  Sometimes that's the problem.

Comment: How do I check what value is returned from the ExecuteNonQuery command? I check my database by opening it up and then opening up the table. It is an Access database.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns an integer telling you how many rows were effected, which in your code you do not capture; store the value in a variable e.g. `var x = com.ExecuteNonQuery();` and either print it somewhere or check it in the debugger.

Comment: I'm tyring to use the System.Console.Writeline(), but it doesn't seem to show anything when I trigger the call for my function.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons this is happening, without more information from you, this is just a shot in the dark.

1. Make sure you have write permissions to the database.
2. Try modifying your connection string to using either computer name or IP address instead of |DataDirectory| to connect.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The person who posted it does not have a high enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: That is correct, Dan. Sorry if it doesn't pass your muster, Mike, but it's currently the only way for me to try and help other users.

Comment: Your best bet to pass community muster is to rephrase this as an answer where this is a list of things to try.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, George!

Comment: Absolutely has write permissions. It's on my local machine right now. It is working with other INSERT statements I have throughout my site. I don't want to change the "Data Directory" part because it will end up on a GoDaddy server later.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 It's not *my* muster. Since you were new, I was letting you know that you shouldn't post comments as answer. Either answer it, or get enough reputation to comment. And FYI, I did not downvote your comment/answer. Was trying to help before you got downvoted more or had it removed by moderator.

Comment: @Joseph about your concerns about deploying to GoDaddy, you should look into web.config transformations on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) or [this old post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx). Handles specifically this issue.

Comment: It currently works on GoDaddy. I'm really just trying to get my insert to work.

Answer (score 0):

What is the underlining column data type? Because depending on the data type for Microsoft Access, the blob/binary have different size.

According to [Data Type Support (OLE DB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- **BigBinary** *DBTYPE_BYTES* 4,000 bytes
- **LongBinary** *DBTYPE_BYTES* 1,073,741,823 bytes
- **VarBinary** *DBTYPE_BYTES* 510 bytes

Also, why don't you use the [SQL Server Express with ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? It's [free](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database/free-database.aspx).

The command string to attached a SQL Express file is easy:

```
string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=e:\data\Customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Comment: Believe you me, next time I will be using SSE. The underlying data type is a string.